# How to sort a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am checking my servers Disk Space Usage and generate a text file as a report.
I want to sort the output file in an ascending order of FreePercentage Free%.

I am stuck at this stage. It just does not sort.
Is it a delimiter issue? Where is my mistake?

```
# files to be used
$FileName0 = "C:\MONITORING\WINDOWS-SPACE\SCRIPT\SPACE0.txt"
$FileName1 = "C:\MONITORING\WINDOWS-SPACE\SCRIPT\SPACE1.txt"
$FileName2 = "C:\MONITORING\WINDOWS-SPACE\SCRIPT\SPACE2.txt"

# file containing servers list
#$ServerName = Get-Content "C:\MONITORING\WINDOWS-SPACE\SCRIPT\COMPUTERS.txt"

# use 2 servers only for coding test, will be replaced by a file containing all
# servers
$ServerName = "SERVER1","SERVER2"

# loop and process drive-id and calculations and populate filename-0
foreach ($_ in $ServerName) {
  Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from win32_logicaldisk"  -ComputerName $_ |
    Select PSComputername, DeviceID,
      @{Name="TotalGB"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -F ($_.Size/1GB)}}, 
      @{Name="UsedGB" ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -F (($_.Size/1GB)-($_.Freespace/1GB))}},
      @{Name="FreeGB" ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -F ($_.Freespace/1GB)}}, 
      @{Name="Free%"  ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -F (($_.Freespace/$_.Size)*100)}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize >> $FileName0
}

# remove unwanted drives ('A'&'Z') and duplicate lines and empty lines and
# populate filename-1
Get-Content $FileName0 | Select-Object -Unique |
  Where {$_ -notmatch "A:"} |
  Where {$_ -notmatch "Z:"} |
  Where { $_ -notmatch "^-" } |
  Where {$_ -ne ""} |
  Format-Table -AutoSize > $FileName1   

# input final result into a CSV file filename-2
Import-Csv $FileName1 -Header PSComputername, TotalGB, UsedGB, FreeGB, Free%  |
  sort [int]Free% |
  Format-Table -AutoSize >> $FileName2
```

Actual output file:

```
PSComputerName DeviceID TotalGB UsedGB FreeGB Free%
SERVER1        C:       60      33     27     45
SERVER1        D:       20      2      18     88
SERVER2        C:       40      27     13     33
SERVER2        D:       50      6      44     87
```

Desired output file:

```
PSComputerName DeviceID TotalGB UsedGB FreeGB Free%
SERVER2        C:       40      27     13     33
SERVER1        C:       60      33     27     45
SERVER2        D:       50      6      44     87
SERVER1        D:       20      2      18     88
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter way to do what you are asking:

```
$computerList = "server1","server2"
$computerList | ForEach-Object {
  $computerName = $_
  $params = @{
    "Class" = "Win32_LogicalDisk"
    "ComputerName" = $computerName
    "Filter" = "DriveType=3"
  }
  Get-WmiObject @params | Select-Object `
    @{Name = "ComputerName"; Expression = {$_.__SERVER}},
    @{Name = "Drive";        Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},
    @{Name = "TotalGB";      Expression = {[Int] ("{0:N0}" -f ($_.Size / 1gb)                         )}},
    @{Name = "UsedGB";       Expression = {[Int] ("{0:N0}" -f (($_.Size / 1gb) - ($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)))}},
    @{Name = "FreeGB";       Expression = {[Int] ("{0:N0}" -f ($_.FreeSpace / 1gb)                    )}},
    @{Name = "FreePercent";  Expression = {[Int] ("{0:N0}" -f (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) * 100)        )}}
} | Sort-Object FreePercent
```

The problem you have is trying to use formatting and sorting before you're done creating output. Make sure you output everything before you try to format or sort.

Comment: `FreePercent` are string values, so you need `Sort-Object {[int]$_.FreePercent}` to get the results in the correct order.

Comment: Correct, I noticed that after I posted and updated to cast all of the values to `[Int]`.

Comment: *\*cough\** `[int]($_.Size / 1gb)` *\*cough\**

Answer (score 2):

`Get-WmiObject` accepts a list of computernames, so you don't need a loop. Your main issue, though, is that you pipe your WMI result through `Format-Table`, write it to a file, and then try to read it again with `Import-Csv` when the format of your intermediate file isn't CSV at all. Sort the data right after `Get-WmiObject` *before* writing it to a file.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk' -ComputerName $ServerName |
  Select PSComputername, DeviceID,
    @{Name="TotalGB"; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Size/1GB)}}, 
    @{Name="UsedGB" ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f (($_.Size/1GB)-($_.Freespace/1GB))}},
    @{Name="FreeGB" ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Freespace/1GB)}}, 
    @{Name="Free%"  ; Expression={"{0:N0}" -f (($_.Freespace/$_.Size)*100)}} |
  Sort-Object {[int]$_.'Free%'} |
  Format-Table -AutoSize |
  Set-Content $FileName2
```

Use `Export-Csv` instead of `Format-Table | Set-Content` if you want actual CSV output:

```
... | Sort-Object [int]$_.Free% | Export-Csv $FileName2 -NoType
```